# How to determine screen size using the context module programatically?

Tags: 7

I have created a node template that needs to display content differently depending on screen size. Basically I have quicktabs being rendered horizontally when in desktop mode and then would like to display those quicktabs in accordion mode when in mobile view.

I have the context and context breakpoint module installed. I would like to know what the current screen resolution is so that I can display the quicktabs accordingly. The module talks about cookies containing that information but I when I look at the cookie, there is no information there. I was wondering if there is a function call to get this information.